# MySQL: how to select rows by date every n days

Tags: mysql, date

I need to get all rows, by an ISO `datetime` field, EVERY "n" (eg. 180) days (note: NOT only the last 180 days).

For example, I need to select every single row at 180 days, 360 days, and so on.

So, for example, if I have a record with date `2016-01-11 12:30:00`, I'll get this record when `DATE()` is `2016-07-09`, `2017-01-05`, `2017-07-04`, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function of MySQL

**Demo**: http://rextester.com/AEIN10581

```
set @QUERY_DATE='2016-07-09';
SELECT * FROM `dates`
    WHERE DATEDIFF(`date`, @QUERY_DATE) % 180 = 0;
```

In place of `@QUERY_DATE`, you can use `CURDATE()` for current date.

Comment: I found the same solution, but using MOD() function. Thanks

Comment: Great. `%` is syntactic sugar for  `MOD()` so it is up to individual preference. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod